# Derivative of the quotient map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R / T\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

We consider the quotient space $\mathbb R /  T\mathbb{Z}$ and the quotient map $\pi:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb R /  T\mathbb{Z}\ $ defined by $\pi(t):= t\bmod T:=t+T\mathbb{Z}$. In a journal i read that $\frac{d}{dt} \pi(t) =1$. Is it true ? If yes, how can i prove it? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: for each $t$ take $k\in\Bbb Z$ s.t. $t - kT\in[0,T)$.

Comment: yeah okay, but why can i choose for each t a representative of the äquivalent class $t+T\mathbb{Z}$ such that the derivatives are equal? And what happends for $t=nT$?  I know that $t \bmod T:=\tilde{t}\in [0,T)$ has derivative 1 if $t\in (0,T)$ and that the derivative is not defined for $t=nT$, but here $t \bmod T := t+T\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, in the border points $t = nT$, $\pi$ is defined via a piecewise function and *apparently* discontinuous. But taking the quotient all is OK. Write *explicitly* charts around all the points of $\Bbb R/T\Bbb Z$ (two cases).

Comment: Did you mean a homeomorphism $\phi$ from a subset of $\mathbb{R} / T\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: Sorry for my questions. I have no basic knowledge in general manifolds ( charts, atlas,...). But i try it...

Comment: can you give me a hint?...

Comment: And saying that $\pi'(t) = 1$ is an abuse of notation.

Answer (score 0):

I will use $[\cdots]$ for the class of... and $\lfloor\cdots\rfloor$ for integer part (max integer $\le\cdots$).

Easy case: $t_0\in(0,T)$. Let be $V = \{[t]:t\in(0,T)\}$, nhod of $t_0$ in the quotient. A chart $\varphi:V\longrightarrow(0,T)$ is
$$[t]\mapsto t - \lfloor t\rfloor.$$

Less esay case: $t_0 = 0$. Let be $W = \{[t]:t\in(-T/2,T/2)\}$ nhod of $0$ in the quotient. Now, a chart $\psi:W\longrightarrow(0,T)$ is
$$[t]\mapsto t + T/2 - \lfloor t + T/2\rfloor.$$

With this definitions, we can write the compositions:
$${\Bbb R}\longrightarrow V\longrightarrow (0,T),$$
$$
t\longmapsto\pi(t) = [t]\longmapsto\varphi\circ\pi(t) =
\varphi([t]) = t - \lfloor t\rfloor.
$$

$${\Bbb R}\longrightarrow W\longrightarrow (0,T),$$
$$
t\longmapsto\pi(t) = [t]\longmapsto\psi\circ\pi(t) =
\psi([t]) = t + T/2 - \lfloor t + T/2\rfloor.
$$
And now observe that the terms $\lfloor t\rfloor$ and $T/2 - \lfloor t + T/2\rfloor$ are locally constant.

Comment: Case1: $t_0\in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{kT:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Let be $U=(kT,(k+1)T)$, nhod of $t_0$. Then $\pi(t)=[t]$ for $t\in U$ (inverse of the first chart). Case2: $t_0\in  \{kT:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Let be $U=(kT-\frac{T}{2},(k+1)T-\frac{T}{2})$, nhod of $t_0$. Then $\pi(t)=[t]$ for $kT\leq t<  ((k+1)T-\frac{T}{2})$ and $\pi(t)=[t-T]$ for $kT-\frac{T}{2}< t<  kT$ ???....

Comment: @Thomas_R, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks. Why are the charts continuous?  Isn`t the integer part a problem? I see that the terms are locally constant, but how does it help me with my question?

Comment: @Thomas_R, by definition of quotient topology, $\varphi$, $\psi$ are continuous because the composition with $\pi$ is continuous (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212041/how-do-i-prove-that-a-map-from-a-quotient-space-is-continuous).

Comment: @Thomas_R, also: $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: okay thanks. And this is the answer to my question? I cant see the connection..

Comment: @Thomas_R, composing with charts $(\varphi\circ\pi)'(t) = 1$ *exactly* while $\pi'(t)$ is a *tangent vector*. Again: $\pi'(t) = 1$ is an abuse of notation.

Comment: @Thomas_R, correction $\pi'(t)$ is a linear map between tangent spaces (spaces of tangent vectors): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385380/why-is-the-diffential-of-a-map-between-manifolds-a-map-between-the-tangent-space.